# How to make a DB Oracle be multi-language

Tags: oracle, plsql, internationalization

I'm looking for a solution to make a DB Oracle as a multi-language DB, our necessity is like this, we've a DB that for instance some business operations are executed through stored procedures and we store any message in a varchar column or when it gets errors, like business logic errors, we used to throw a raise application error with a message to outside.
Now we have to store this messages in three different languages and throw this messages also in three different languages.

As I'm looking for solutions, any kind of suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a new column on the error messages table, and for each row, a value saying which language it is in. For example: `lang ( EN | FR | ES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much approaches for this.

I would list the most popular from it:

1) Duplicate tables. I.e. create tables: customer_en, customer_fr, customer_ge etc

2) Create dictionary for each entity table. I.e., you will have the table Customer (id, name, short_name, description) with English texts. And the table Customer_Voc (id, customer_id, short_name, description, languages). Customer_Voc will be in X time bigger then Customer table. Where X is number of supported non-English languages.

3) Use languages related columns in the table. In our case: 
Customer (Id, short_name_en, short_name_fr,short_name_de, ... , description_en, description_fr, description_de)

4) Use common vocabulary. 
In this case you will have 2 additional table:

phrases - ID, eng_text 
phrases_translation - ID, phrases_id, translated_text, language

And each text field you should replace by fk on phrases.ID

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your answer, I will create tables to concentrate all my messages for all languages, it is a simple and an effective way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking that the NLS Character set will accommodate all the message content that you expect to have in the table. It's easy to migrate from a character subset to superset, but hard to go the other way.

There's a [description of a Multilingual Database Scenario](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm) on Oracle's site, and the same details are available for older versions of Oracle.